# How I increase my box of inputText in pysimplegui?

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I used size but nothing changed:

```
input = [
    [sg.Text("Type your text")],
    [sg.InputText(key='text', size=(200,200))],
    [sg.Button("Sent")]
]

wInput = sg.Window("Exercicio Python", input, size=(400,450))

while True:
    events, values = wInput.read()
    if events == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

What I have:

[image]

What I wanted:

[image]

Comment: The purpose of an `sg.InputText` element is to let the user see and modify a single line of text. `sg.Multiline` elements are a much more generalized method for handling multiple lines of text than the `sg.InputText` element. `sg.Multiline` elements are pretty much a complete text editor in a window. The option `size` of `sg.InputText` is `(w, h)` where w=characters-wide and h=rows-high, not number of points or pixels.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
I used :

    input = [
    [sg.Text("Type your text")],
    [sg.Multiline(key="texto", size=(50, 20))],
    [sg.Button("Sent")]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
input = [
    [sg.Text("Type your text")],
    [sg.InputText(key='text', size=(200,200), expand_y=True)],
    [sg.Button("Sent")]
]

wInput = sg.Window("Exercicio Python", input, size=(400,450))

while True:
    events, values = wInput.read()
    if events == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
```

The expand_y=boolean and expand_x=boolean will stretch the items in x width and y height. Try adding both to your InputText and the x to your button. Pls let me know if it worked for you ;-)